# Error add Byte in LinkedList<Byte>

Tags: java

Why can't I do :

```
Byte b = new Byte("0");

LinkedList<Byte> begin = new LinkedList<Byte>().add(b);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the result of `new LinkedList().add(b);` is not a `LinkedList`. It is `boolean`.

Comment: How to initial `begin` with Bye("0") ?

Comment: If you really need to do this in one line do: `new LinkedList<Byte>(java.util.Arrays.asList((byte)0));`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
List<Byte> begin = new LinkedList<Byte>();
byte b = 0;
begin.add(b);
```

if you want a collection of bytes there a number of collections which are much more efficient for doing this. e.g. a LinkedList will use about 20 bytes per byte you add.  Try using

- ArrayList (4 bytes per actual byte),
- ByteArrayOutputStream (1 byte per byte) and ByteArrayInputStream (1 byte per byte) or
- ByteBuffer (1 byte per byte).

Answer (score 1):

**new LinkedList().add(b);** doesnt return a linkedlist object
 try

```
Byte b = new Byte("0");
LinkedList<Byte> list= new LinkedList<Byte>();
list.add(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedList<Byte> begin = new LinkedList<Byte>()
begin.add(b);
```